# Empty space in an anchor layout

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there any way of getting empty space into an anchor layout?

I would like an empty space before I add my components. Note: I cannot use margins.

```
layout: {
    type: 'anchor'
},
items : [

    {
        xtype: 'hidden',
        anchor: '50% -2'
    }

}
```

I have also tried :

```
 {
      xtype : 'label',
      text  : '',
      labelSeparator: '',
      anchor: '50% -2'
 },
```

Comment: Where do you want that space? Horizontally? If so change anchor to '-100 -2' - then you get 100 pixels on the item's right and 2 pixels on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in the end :

```
{
   xtype: 'label',
   html: '&nbsp;'
},
```